# Identifying and removing this weed / clovers from my lawn / groundcover

Tags: lawn, weed-control, weeds, clover

There is one side of my yard that has this particular weed along with clovers.

[image]

It was on the lawn last year, but this year it's gotten worse and is spreading into my groundcover bed. I'm going to finish adding rocks around the bed to keep it from leeching in from the lawn more.

[image]

What is it and how can I remove it?

Additional pictures:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Creeping Charlie (Glechoma hederacea). You will have to pull out the creeping charlie by hand in your ground cover area. In the lawn area, look for a herbicide for Chickweed, Clover and Oxalis Killer. Ortho Weed-B-Gone Chickweed, Clover and Oxalis Killer is one. Look for the ingredient "triclopyr." Get a tank sprayer. Also add a surfactant or "sticker" to the herbicide to help it to stick to the waxy leaf surfaces. You may need to spray again after a few weeks. Once you have the creeping charlie under control, learn to mow higher. I mow at 4 inches which is the highest setting on my mower.

Comment: This was the information I was looking for. Thanks! I set my mower to 3 inches, but I will start doing the highest setting.  I just got this house last year and I'm getting some of the yard problems under control.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Creeping Charlie, if you pull it out diligently then it'll give up eventually. Broadleaf herbicide works too, might need two applications though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like mallow.  Leaves are edible.  Has a deep root system so will be difficult to remove.  Best way to deal with this is keep the turf healthy which will drown out the mallow and clover

Comment: I'm mostly concerned with the groundcover area... if I water and fertilize it, won't it just help the mallow more? I plan on using some weed control in the grassy area, but I'm sure I can't use it in the pachysandra.